# Can I add a Unity game to an already existing Windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, windows-8.1, unityscript

So I really tried to look for an answer and I've tried to solve this myself to no success. I'm sorry if there's already a solution and I just can't find it...

I know you can make a Unity game FOR Windows 8, meaning once I build in Unity for Windows 8, I can open/debug it in Visual Studio, yada yada yada.

What I wanted to do once I'm on VS is either:

- Add pages before launching the game by changing the opening page. Searched the net for this, but since Unity changes the code template, I don't know hot to do this anymore
- Add the Unity game into an existing Windows 8 app. Basically I click one of the items/buttons and it's going to launch the game

I'm using C# now but if this is possible in JS, it's fine. Is this even possible or should I just do everything in Unity?

Comment: Honestly I'd just make an additional scene in unity in your w8 build that does what you want. For additional integration I suspect that you would require a more complex solution involving native api hooks into w8. Save yourself some pain.